# get_terms showing all categories instead of the ones assigned to a specific post

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I have 3 posts in my custom post type (`'careers'`). I registered a custom taxonomy of (`'career_categories'`).

I created 3 posts and assigned two of them with a category of "Full-Time" and one with "Part-Time".

I am using the following code in my loop:

```
$terms = get_terms( 'career_categories', array( 'hide_empty' => true, ) );

$html_out .= '<td class="column-'. $col++ .'">';
   if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) :
      foreach( $terms as $term) :
         $html_out .= $term->name;
      endforeach;
   endif;
$html_out .= '</td>';
```

On the front-end this is displaying both categories on each post. I need it to show only the category selected for the post.

**Currently**
Job 1 - Full-TimePart-Time
Job 2 - Full-TimePart-Time
Job 3 - Full-TimePart-Time

**Expected**
Job 1 - Full-Time
Job 2 - Full-Time
Job 3 - Part-Time

Answer (score 2):

There are two functions:

[get_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/)

```
get_terms( string|array $args = array(), array $deprecated = '' )
```

Which retrieves the terms in a given taxonomy or list of taxonomies.

And...

[get_the_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/)

```
get_the_terms( int|object $post, string $taxonomy )
```

Which retrieves the terms of the taxonomy that are attached to the post.

You should use second one in your case, I guess...

Comment: Ugh, kicking myself right now. This is correct. Thanks!

Comment: `get_object_terms` is a lower level and more useful function that can also be used

Comment: @Darren if this is the correct answer can you mark it as correct? That way Krzysiek Dróżdż gets the reputation points and others with your problem can see this worked